# Is there a way to yield all combinations of two arrays one by one using a generator function?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, yield

I am trying to yield the combinations of two array with the use of a
generator , but the i,j values remain the same.

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4]
array2 = [4,5]

def testyield():

    global array1
    global array2

    for i in range (0,len(array1)):
        for j in range (0,len(array2)):
            yield array1[i],array2[j]


print next(testyield())
print next(testyield())
print next(testyield())
print next(testyield())
```

I expect the output of (1,4) (1,5) (2,4) (2,5) , but the actual output is (1,4) (1,4) (1,4) (1,4)

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.product`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new generator each time you call `testyield()`

What you must do is assign it to a variable and then call `next` on your generator:

```
my_gen = testyield()
print next(my_gen) # (1, 4)
print next(my_gen) # (1, 5)
print next(my_gen) # (2, 4)
print next(my_gen) # (2, 5)
```

As other said, if your goal is to make good code, take a look at `itertools.product` which answers your question directly:

```
from itertools import product
for e in product(array1, array2):
    print e
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.product()` is probably what you're looking for. It returns a generator:

```
import itertools
array1 = [1,2,3,4]
array2 = [4,5]

for x in itertools.product(array1, array2):
    print(x)
# (1, 4)
# (1, 5)
# (2, 4)
# (2, 5)
# (3, 4)
# (3, 5)
# (4, 4)
# (4, 5)
```

But to make your code work use it this way:

```
for x in testyield():
    print(x)
```